# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly C#

Tags: c#

I was created one cpp GOQii_API.dll with clr support and which uses the another dll (dongle.dll).and this  GOQii_API.dll used in my C# code.

the above structure  is working very well in both system 32bit and 64 bit where visual studio 2010 is installed.

but, When i created mis setup and installed on fresh machine where development environment is not present. Then it gives me following error.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'GOQii_API.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: GOQii_API.dll

Comment: Make sure any dependent .dlls (like C+ runtime msvcrt) are installed on the new machine, as it's possible your cpp dll requires them.

Comment: might guess would be, that you proberly didn't install the GOQii_API inside the same folder, on the computer you are trying to run your program from.
if you are trying to make a standalone installer, remember to add GOQii_API as a dependency

Comment: i was placed the all .dll in same location.still show same problem. In development environment or fresh windows xp 32 bit machine it is working fine.but shows error in  windows 7 32 bit or 64bit machine.

Comment: Thank u friends. I got the solution by using the "Process walker tool"  i missed to copy "msvcr100d.dll" with my source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank u friends.

I got the solution by using the "Process walker tool"  i missed to copy "msvcr100d.dll" with my source code.

use "Process walker tool" shows you what dependency .dll required and you missed.